# How can I shoot down a meteorite in Surviving Mars?

Tags: achievements, surviving-mars

A Steam achievement is named **A Shooting Star**

> Shoot down a meteorite

How is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tech in the physics row called **Meteor Defense System**, it should appear fairly late, costing at least 8000 research points.

This tech allows you to build MDS-Lasers, small gun turrets  capable of shooting down meteors within a medium radius.

When a meteor drops within range, the MDS shoots it down and you get this achievement.

Additionally, you can use those turrets to protect your colony against the threats created by some of mysteries.